# Telegram bot не обрабатывает инлайн клавиатуру

Tags: php, telegram-bot

Написал бота, который по команде должен вывести сообщение с динамической инлайн клавиатурой, но он выводит только ошибку - Bad Request: can't parse inline keyboard button: InlineKeyboardButton must be an Object

```
        for ($i = 0; $i < $array_count; $i++) {
        $token_get = secret_token_get($user_id)[$i];
        $token_symbols = substr($token_get['token'], -5);

        global $buttons;
        $buttons = secret_token_get($user_id);
        $buttons = array_map(function ($token_symbols) {
            return [[['text' => $token_symbols, 'callback_data' => $token_symbols]]];
            }, $buttons);
        }
    $post = [
        'chat_id' => $user_id,
        'text' => '<b>All your private tokens are listed here: </b>',
        'parse_mode' => 'html',
        'reply_markup' => inline_keyboard($buttons)
    ];
    sendRequest('sendMessage', $post);
```

Ответ от Telegram:

```
{
"chat_id": 915597301,
"text": "<b>All your private tokens are listed here: </b>",
"parse_mode": "html",
"reply_markup": "{\"inline_keyboard\":[[[{\"text\":{\"token\":\"123\"},\"callback_data\":{\"token\":\"123\"}}]],[[{\"text\":{\"token\":\"321\"},\"callback_data\":{\"token\":\"321\"}}]],[[{\"text\":{\"token\":\"213\"},\"callback_data\":{\"token\":\"213\"}}]]]}"
}

Bad Request: can't parse inline keyboard button: InlineKeyboardButton must be an Object
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему переделав структуру

```
function inline_keyboard($array) {
return json_encode(['inline_keyboard' => $array]);
}

if ($array_count !== 0) {

    $rows = $array_count;
    $columns = 1;
    $keyboard = [];
    for ($i = 0; $i < $rows; $i++) {
        $rowKeys = [];
        for ($j = 1; $j <= $columns; $j++) {
            $token_get = secret_token_get($user_id)[$i];
            $token_symbols = substr($token_get['token'], -5);
            $rowKeys[] = ['text' => $token_symbols, 'callback_data' => 
$token_symbols];
        }
        $keyboard[] = $rowKeys;
    }

    // Вывод клавиатуры
    $post = [
        'chat_id' => $user_id,
        'text' => '<b>For security purposes, the last 5 characters of 
the private token will be displayed</b>' . "\n\n" .
            '<b>All your private tokens are listed here: </b>',
        'parse_mode' => 'html',
        'reply_markup' => inline_keyboard($keyboard)
    ];
    sendRequest('sendMessage', $post);
}
```